# Test differently binned data sets

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I am trying to test how a periodic data set behaves with respect to the same data set folded with the period (that is, the average profile). More specifically, I want to test if the single profiles are consistent with the average one.

I am reading about a number of test available in Python, especially about [the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic on 2 samples](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html) and the [chi square test](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html).

However, my data are real data, and binned of course.

Therefore, as it is frequent, my data have gaps in between. This means that very often the number of bins in the single profiles is less than the bins of the "model" (the folded/average profile).

This means that I can't use those tests straightforward (because the two arrays have different number of elements), but I probably need to:

1) do some transformation, or any other operation, that allows me to compare the distributions;

2) Also, converting the average profile into a continuous model would be a nice solution;

3) Proceed with different statistical instruments which I am not aware of.

But I don't know how to move on in either case, so I would need help in finding a way for (1) or (2) (perhaps both!), or a hint about the third case.

EDIT: the data are a light curve, that is photon counts versus time.
The data are from a periodic astronomical source, that is they repeat their pattern (profile) every given period. I can fold the data with the period and obtain an average profile, and I want to use this averaged profile as a model to test each single profile against the averaged one, that is my model.
Thanks!

Comment: I think *Kernel Density Estimator* based method *goodness-of-fit* test for *binned data* probably would be your best choice. `Python` is probably limited in that aspect. But see `R`: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bda/bda.pdf, especially the `gof.test` function. Let me know if you want to run though a real example

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out. At a first glance at the guide you liked, it seems that the `gof.test` in R is generic. Which gof test does it perform?

Comment: Per doc: 'An R object obtained from ﬁtting a distribution to a data set. Supported classes include ’gamma’,’norm’,’weibull’,’bde’, ’em'. You want to use it for `bde` which standards for 'Density Estimation for Binned Data'.

Comment: This sounds like a question for http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Warren: I am also asking in stats SE, but for the statistical instruments, not for the python tools.

Comment: @CTZhu yes please, could you give me some examples? I never used R.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what test you want? I.e. do you have a bunch of profiles and you want to test if they're all equal, and to do this you're testing each against the average? Or do you have some model from somewhere else that you want to test against each profile in turn? As always, it helps to show us (an example) of your data, and what you'd like to test (not how to do what you think is the correct test!)

Comment: @BenAllison I want to test each one against the average. In other words, the average profile is my model. I will add some more information about my data in the main topic. Thanks!

Comment: Then I think what you want to test is the hypothesis that bin proportions are not equal across profiles, and testing against the average is how you think you should do this. Instead, you could look at the Chi-Squared test for contingency tables.